# Using the Eloquent ORM on a table with two types of records

Tags: orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm wondering if there was a way to do the following with the Eloquent ORM:

I have a table for Build Actions, there can be two types of build actions, each of these actions have their own table with data unique to them and a foreign key back to the build action, as shown below:

[image: My tables]

So currently I have an Eloquent model for a Build Action, a model for the build supplies table and a model for the build timings table, how would I use Eloquent to check the type of record in the build action table, then use the appropriate relationship to load the data from the correct table? So if the build action was a timing, I would want to display the timing before the action text, and vice versa if the build action was a supply based action.

Comment: I think that the polymorphic relationships is the thing you might be looking for. Check out [the docs here](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations) But you'd possibly have to refactor you db scheme a bit, so just a suggestion not an answer :)

Comment: Ooh thank you, this looks very promising, and yes it looks like some refactoring will be needed, but that isn't a big issue, thanks a lot, I'll get back to you with the results of using this :)